# Python proper code formatting (PEP8)

Tags: python, code-formatting, pep8

So I just learned about ["List Comprehensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892154/dynamic-session-access-in-templates/6892221#6892221) in python.  some of these are getting too long for a single line (PEP8) and I'm trying to figure out the best (most readable) way to break these out.

I've come up with this

```
questions = [
    (
        q,
        q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='Y'),
        q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='N'),
        request.session.get(str(q.id))
    )
    for q in questions
]
```

but it still complains about whitespace before the `]`, the specific pep8 error is `E202`

this is in an indented block.

Comment: what tool are you using to "check" your code?  pylint?

Comment: the pep8 textmate bundle

Comment: `choice__exact` should be `choice_exact` if you're so interested in pep8. BTW I wouldn't care so much about multiline list comprehensions identation. Just make it readable.

Comment: @JBernardo I suspect the `choice__exact` name comes from Django API.

Comment: The PEP only gives special meaning to underscores at the beginning and end of the line. It gives no opinion on internal double underscores.

Comment: Note that this is very inefficient from a Django point of view - two db hits for each element in questions.

Comment: @Daniel I'd love to hear how you'd do it different, I'm just learning Django...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

```
questions = [(q, 
              q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='Y'), 
              q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='N'), 
              request.session.get(str(q.id)))
                  for q in questions]
```

Keep in mind that PEP8 is intended to be used along with your best judgement; they aren't intended to be followed absolutely in all circumstances. They also aren't structured to always make sense when multiple rules conflict.

It's OK to **intentionally** break the rules once in a while; checkers like that are just intended to make sure you don't break them **accidentally**.

Edit: Moving my comment into my answer.

Your code looks a little bit too much like a Lisp-like parenthesis language or a C-like curly-braces language because of you putting brackets and parenthesis on separate lines.

In Python, you just use indentation to show what you would normally show with a bracket / parenthesis / brace on a separate line in another language. If you take your code and make that change, it's identical to my version.

Really though, don't worry too much about the PEP checker. If you really like the extra whitespace you get from putting the parenthesis and brackets on separate lines, then do it. It doesn't make it "bad code" nor does it decrease the readability.

Comment: right, I'm just new to python, so I just didn't know if there was a better way to break these out and want to write quality code from the git go.

Comment: Yeah separate lines for the sake of it doesn't seem like a good idea to me. This one feels right.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon to the tool, I guess. Which tool is giving you E202? I copy pasted and tried with this [pep8](http://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/) tool and it did not give any error. But I specifically but a whitespace after `questions` and got the error.

The E202 on the `]` says that it is finding a whitespace before that. Make sure that you don't have that in the code. Try closing `]` soon after questions.

Comment: well there is whitespace before it because it is inside a codeblock.

Comment: He means that the line it's on is indented. This actually wouldn't matter as a newline is whitepace anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing your statement using a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

```
questions = ((q,
              q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='Y'),
              q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='N'),
              request.session.get(str(q.id)),) 
             for q in questions)
```

Additionally, not that its "wrong", but in general I don't recommend redefining declared variables cause it may cause confusion in the code. In this case you are changing the `questions` instance to another type.

Comment: Only use a generator expression if you will only ever need to iterate over the new `questions` object once. I don't think this is a good use for generator expressions at all.

Comment: Yes context matters. In the right situation, generators are better cause you can postpone a lot of the method calls until the results are more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to reproduce your PEP8 warning with the code you showed above. Perhaps you could put your exact code in a pastebin?

The example test cases for PEP8 (if you use the --show-pep8 option) are as follows:

```
Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:

- Immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces.

- Immediately before a comma, semicolon, or colon.

Okay: spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2})
E201: spam( ham[1], {eggs: 2})
E201: spam(ham[ 1], {eggs: 2})
E201: spam(ham[1], { eggs: 2})
E202: spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2} )
E202: spam(ham[1 ], {eggs: 2})
E202: spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2 })

E203: if x == 4: print x, y; x, y = y , x
E203: if x == 4: print x, y ; x, y = y, x
E203: if x == 4 : print x, y; x, y = y, x
```

Also, I haven't actually used Textmate, but if you're doing on the fly checking similar to emacs' flymake mode, then it could also be that pep8 is getting called on an old version of the file, and the issue may go away when you save the file. We may need more information to debug further.

As for the formatting of the list comprehension itself, you may want to take a look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809059/line-continuation-for-list-comprehensions-or-generator-expressions-in-python) as well as [the take from the Google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=List_Comprehensions#List_Comprehensions). I personally have no problem with the way you did it. I suppose you could also do something like

```
def _question_tuple(q):
    return (
        q,
        q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='Y'),
        q.vote_set.filter(choice__exact='N'),
        request.session.get(str(q.id))
    )

question_tups = [_question_tuple(q) for q in questions]
```

but it's really about what will be the most readable/maintainable, and that's up to your own judgment.

Comment: He clearly has whitespace / newlines before the closing `)` and `]`. this violates the rule in his tool.